# Formidable keeps uploading files even If i sent errors

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, next.js

I am using next js as frontend and everything is working and the file is actually getting uploaded but here when I try to tell if the file is not PDF/Images or if the size is 5MB return an error and do not upload it but what it does it keeps sending error to the frontend and also keeps uploading the file , why that happens , I just want to prevent file upload if the file is not pdf or image and not higher than 5MB .

```
import { NextApiHandler } from "next";
import { IncomingForm } from 'formidable';
import path from "path";
import fs from "fs";

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

const readFile = (req: any, res: any) => {
  const uploadDir = path.join(process.cwd(), "/uploads");

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const customOptions = {
      uploadDir: uploadDir,
      keepExtensions: true,
      allowEmptyFiles: false,
      maxFileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024,
      multiples: true,
    };
    const form = new IncomingForm(customOptions);
    const allowedFileTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'application/pdf'];

    let errors : string = '';

    form.on('file', (name, file) => {
      if (!allowedFileTypes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
        errors = ('Invalid file type. Only PDF and image files are allowed');
      }

      if (file.size > customOptions.maxFileSize) {
        errors = ('File size exceeds the limit (5MB).');
      }
    });

    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error parsing form' });
      }

      const email = fields.email[0];

      if (!email) {
        errors = ('Email field is required');
      }

      const emailFolder = path.join(uploadDir, email);
      if (!fs.existsSync(emailFolder)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(emailFolder, { recursive: true });
      }

      const updatedFiles = files.myfiles?.map((file) => {
        const originalFilePath = path.join(emailFolder, file.originalFilename);
        let counter = 1;
        let newFilePath = originalFilePath;

        while (fs.existsSync(newFilePath)) {
          const fileNameWithoutExt = path.parse(originalFilePath).name;
          const fileExt = path.parse(originalFilePath).ext;
          newFilePath = path.join(emailFolder, `${fileNameWithoutExt}-${counter}${fileExt}`);
          counter += 1;
        }

        fs.renameSync(file.filepath, newFilePath);
        return { ...file, filepath: newFilePath };
      });

      if (errors.length > 0) {
        return res.json({ errors });
      }

      resolve({ files: updatedFiles });
    });
  });
};


const handler: NextApiHandler = async (req, res) => {
  if(req.method === "POST"){
  try {
    const data = await readFile(req, res);
    res.status(200).json({ data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error processing file upload:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: true, message: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
}
};

export default handler;
```